# What does the subversion error "Could not read status line" mean?

Tags: svn

This is a fairly basic question, but it is driving me nuts. I have set up a brand new repository at beanstalk.com. They give me the url, http://my_name.svn.beanstalkapp.com/blog. They also automatically create the tag, trunk and branches folder in the repository. I have checked out the trunk folder and used

```
svn add
```

to add the new file. I am trying to do my first commit, but I get this error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
CHECKOUT of '/foo/!svn/bln/1': Could not read status line: 
connection was closed by server. (http://user_name@my_name.svn.beanstalkapp.com)
```

What does this mean, and what causes it? I have googled for a definition of what  "Could not read status line" means, but was unable to find anything explaining it.

edit: I was getting this error while trying to manipulate my repository from behind a firewall. I still don't know what was causing it, but I don't have this problem at home. Strangeness.

Comment: Is you SVN client up to date?

Comment: Subversion 1.4.4. Dunno if it is the most up to date, but it is working for another project that I am working on. That one was set up by someone else, but in setting up my own repository I am a bit lost.

Comment: You have a "." between the "@" and "svn". Are you sure it is correct? It gives a different message for me but does not work.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part. Should be foo.svn.beanstalkapp.com.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem when I typed the wrong URL:

Bad behavior:

`$ svn list https://zh3.beanstalkapp.com/repo`

To fix the problem, the URL should be:
`https://zh3.svn.beanstalkapp.com/repo`

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue.. until i remebered i needed https at front

Answer (score 2):

I read somewhere that is because the http method. Please change to https to resolve this problem
**https**://my_name.svn.beanstalkapp.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In our case it was the Mcafee antivirus software on the server repository stealing the file when commited via subversion.  Resulting in the svn error.

Disabling the virus software solved our issue.